# Pareto Efficient level of Public Good

Tags: pareto-efficiency, public-goods

As part of self study towards an entrance exam, I am solving the following question.

There are two consumers in the economy and two goods, one private and one public. The utilities of the consumers is given by:

$$u_1(x_1,y) = x_1+6\sqrt y$$

$$u_2(x_2,y = x_2 + 10\sqrt y$$

where $x_i$ is the quantity of the private good and $y$ is the quantity of the public good consumed. Initial endowments of the private goods:

$$\omega_1 = 40, \omega_2 = 60$$.

A unit of private good can be converted one-for-one to a public good.

My attempt:

The Pareto Efficient level of public good is determined by the equation:

$$|MRS_1| + |MRS_2| = MC(G) \quad (1)$$

where $MRS_1 = \frac{MU_G}{MU_{x_1}}$, $MRS_2 = \frac{MU_G}{MU_{x_2}}$ and $MC(G)$ is the marginal cost of providing the public good.

Solving $(1)$ with the given utility functions I get:

$$\frac{3}{\sqrt y} + \frac{5}{\sqrt y} = 1$$
$$\implies y = 64$$

Therefore, the Pareto efficient level of public good is $y=64$.

The question asks to select the Pareto Inefficient bundle $(x_1,x_2,y)$ amongst the following:

A. $(50,0,50)$

B. $(90,0,10)$

C. $(0,80,20)$

D. $(16,20,64)$

I think all of A, B and C are Pareto Inefficient.

The given answer is C.

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The social welfare maximizing outcome you computed (by equating the sum of marginal benefits to marginal cost) is just *one of* the Pareto efficient outcomes. Although maximization of joint utilities is a sufficient condition for Pareto efficiency, it is not a necessary condition. Pareto efficiency is defined by the lack of Pareto improvement -- a reallocation of resources to make at least someone better off without making any other worse off.

Option C is not Pareto efficient because a Pareto improvement exists. At $(0,80,20)$, 
\begin{equation}
u_1(0,20)=0+6\sqrt{20}\approx 26.83 \qquad 
u_2(80,20)=80+10\sqrt{20}\approx124.72. 
\end{equation}
Observe that at this bundle, consumer 2's MU for the good $y$ is $5/\sqrt{20}\approx1.11$ and his MU for $x$ is $1$. Therefore, increasing one unit of good $y$ at the expense of one less unit of $x$ is utility enhancing for consumer 2. At the same time, one extra $y$ benefits consumer 1 as well. So we can easily verify that $(0,79,21)$ is a Pareto improvement over $(0,80,20)$:
\begin{equation}
u_1(0,21)=0+6\sqrt{21}\approx27.495 \qquad 
u_2(79,21)=79+10\sqrt{21}\approx124.83
\end{equation}
where both consumers experience higher utilities.

In a similar way, you should be able to verify that no Pareto improvements exist for options A, B, and D.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following maximisation problem:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_1, x_2, y} & x_1 + 6\sqrt{y} + \alpha(x_2 + 10 \sqrt{y}) \\ \text{s.t.} & x_1 + x_2 +y = 100 \\ \text{and} & x_1\geq 0, x_2 \geq 0,y \geq 0\end{eqnarray*}
which can be re-written as:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_1, x_2, y} & x_1 + \alpha x_2 + 2\beta \sqrt{y} \\ \text{s.t.} & x_1 + x_2 +y = 100 \\ \text{and} & x_1\geq 0, x_2 \geq 0,y \geq 0\end{eqnarray*}
where $\beta = 3 + 5\alpha$.

Clearly, for any $\alpha > 0$, any solution to the above problem is Pareto efficient.
We can now find the set of solutions to the above problem:

\begin{eqnarray*} (x_1^*, x_2^*, y^*)(\alpha) \in \begin{cases} \{(100 - \beta^2,0,\beta^2)\} & \text{if } \alpha < 1 \\ \{(x_1, x_2, y)\in\mathbb{R}^3_+|x_1+x_2=36,y=64\} & \text{if } \alpha = 1 \\ \left\{\left(0,100-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2},\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\right)\right\} & \text{if } \alpha > 1 \end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

Now we can check for Pareto efficiency of the given options:

- Option (a) $(50,0,50)$ is Pareto efficient.  For that consider $\beta = \sqrt{50}$ or when $\alpha = \dfrac{\sqrt{50} -3}{5}$.
- Option (b) $(90,0,10)$ is Pareto efficient.  For that consider $\beta = \sqrt{10}$ or when $\alpha = \dfrac{\sqrt{10} -3}{5}$.
- Option (d) $(16,20,64)$ is Pareto efficient.  For that consider $\alpha = 1$.
- Option (c) $(0,80,20)$ is not Pareto efficient, because $(0,75,25)$ is Pareto superior.

Besides the solutions obtained above, there are two more Pareto efficient allocations: $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+}(x_1^*, x_2^*, y^*)(\alpha) = (91, 0, 9)$ and $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow \infty}(x_1^*, x_2^*, y^*)(\alpha) = (0, 75, 25)$. These are the solutions to the following problems:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_1, x_2, y} & x_1 + 6\sqrt{y} \\ \text{s.t.} & x_1 + x_2 +y = 100 \\ \text{and} & x_1\geq 0, x_2 \geq 0,y \geq 0\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x_1, x_2, y} & x_2 + 10\sqrt{y} \\ \text{s.t.} & x_1 + x_2 +y = 100 \\ \text{and} & x_1\geq 0, x_2 \geq 0,y \geq 0\end{eqnarray*}
respectively.

To see how to find the set of efficient allocations graphically, you can watch this playlist: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUJGfL_499TJIHv2nw4rn40BbQIe8DChz